# Set SnackBar height in Flutter

Tags: flutter

How do I set the height of SnackBar in Flutter?

I have this code from flutter documentation:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const SnackBarDemo());

class SnackBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  const SnackBarDemo({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
  title: 'SnackBar Demo',
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('SnackBar Demo'),
    ),
    body: const SnackBarPage(),
   ),
  );
 }
}

class SnackBarPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SnackBarPage({super.key});

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Center(
     child: ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
      final snackBar = SnackBar(
        content: const Text('Yay! A SnackBar!'),
        action: SnackBarAction(
          label: 'Action name',
          onPressed: () {
            // Some code to undo the change.
          },
        ),
      );

      // Find the ScaffoldMessenger in the widget tree
      // and use it to show a SnackBar.
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
    },
    child: const Text('Show SnackBar'),
   ),
  );
 }
}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

How do I prevent the snack bar to be that big?
I want the text and the action to be on the same line.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put that button in content, like this:

```
onPressed: () {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
        content: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Text('Yay! A SnackBar!'),
              ),
              TextButton(
                 onPressed: () {
                    
                    if (mounted) { // <==== add this for hide snackBar
                       ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();     
                    }

                    // Some code to undo the change.
                 },
                 child: Text(
                   'Action name',
                   style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                 ),
               )
            ],
          ),
      );

    if (mounted) {
       ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);     
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @eamirho3ein, I get the following error: `This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct).
Consider canceling any active work during "dispose" or using the "mounted" getter to determine if the State is still active.`

Answer (score 1):

This is automatic. If there is enough space for both message and action items, it will be shown on same line.

You can try changing the padding of Snackbar. You can try making it float but overall, it is there for responsiveness.

Here is how the framework calculates if items should be placed in single row or across multiple rows.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Changing the content as suggested by @eamirho3ein is working, but the snackbar is not disappearing upon clicking on the button. But I think I might just leave it that way after all.

Answer (score 0):

Use `actionOverflowThreshold` parameter of `SnackBar` or `SnackBarThemeData`.

`actionOverflowThreshold` description from docs:

> The percentage threshold for action widget's width before it overflows
> to a new line.
>
> Must be between 0 and 1. If the width of the snackbar's [content] is
> greater than this percentage of the width of the snackbar less the
> width of its [action], then the [action] will appear below the
> [content].
>
> At a value of 0, the action will not overflow to a new line.
>
> Defaults to 0.25.

Set it to 0.5 or some value higher than the default.